# Validate content of config file C#

Tags: c#, xml, ranorex

I need to validate the contents of an existing config file.

It looks like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <Version>HB.2017.0</Version>
      <FORMAT_VERSION>2.4</FORMAT_VERSION>
      <MISC>Stuff.2014.0</MISC>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I've been trying to write something in C# to read the file and assign the content of the `Version` and `Format-Version` and then validates if it is true or not but I keep getting a null pointer error.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void ValidateConfigVersionSetting()
    {

         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.Load(@"C:\project.exe.config");

         XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Version");

         string nodeContent = node.InnerText;

         if (nodeContent.Equals("2017.0"))
             {
                Report.Success("Config", "Config is correct! 2017.");
             }
         else
            {
                Report.Failure("Config", "Config is not 2017.");
            }    

    }
```

This is a code module for a Ranorex automation suite so the `Validate.IsTrue` comes from that. Is the way I store the `innertext` correct?

Comment: What line are you receiving the null pointer error?

Comment: Why not use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"]`?

Comment: Also, `SelectSingleNode` expects a prefix. Not sure if that is the cause of your error or not. Try just using "Version"

Comment: @emsimpson92 `string nodeContent = node.InnerText;`, tried just Version without the `/` and still happened.

@Stefan I'm unfamiliar with that but I'll look at it right now. Thanks!

Comment: @mjwills `Syntax error, ':' expected (CS1003)` and `Invalid expression term '.' (CS1525)`

Comment: Ah, you are on a old C# compiler - use `string nodeContent = node == null ? string.Empty : (node.InnerText ?? string.Empty);`

Comment: @mjwills It runs now but returns as null, which I believe it shouldn't be.

Comment: There is literally no way that code assigns `null`. Do you mean "" (blank string)? If so, your XPath selector is wrong. Did you try `"/configuration/appSettings/Version"` Or `"//Version"`?

Comment: @mjwills You were right on the money. Tinkered a bit and changed a few lines. Neither or those worked. Instead I went to `appSettings`. Changed the conditional to `if (node.FirstChild.InnerText.Equals("HB.2017.0")` and it runs. Removed `nodeContent` entirely. Told the report to return the value of `node.InnerText` and it returns the entire content of `appSettings`. Don't know why it'll take that but not `Version`.

Comment: Nice. Also, in future use `==` rather than `.Equals`. It protects you against some classes of `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 4):

If that code is exactly as written, then you have a mistake here:

```
Validate.IsTrue(nodeContent="HB.2017.0", "Config is proper");
```

You're assigning the string to nodeContent, not comparing it.

Comment: You're right. I updated accordingly. Should be better, however I still have the object reference not set to an instance error.

Comment: What line is the exception coming from?  You may want to check that the node in question is actually found.